# Simple Query extracting all achievements that user does not have (One-to-Many)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Giving the next tables

**Achievements**

- id
- title
- sub_title
- description

**Achievements_user**

- id
- achievement_id
- user_id

I would like to extract all achievements that the user does not have, I have run a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(achievements.id), achievements.title, 
achievements.sub_title 
FROM achievements 
LEFT JOIN achievements_user 
ON achievements.id=achievements_user.achievement_id 
WHERE achievements_user.user_id != 123 
OR achievements_user.user_id IS NULL
```

But I think that's not a good way.
What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: It's the right kind of idea. You're quite close. Note however that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1):

This return all the achievements that the user 123 does not have

```
SELECT id, title, sub_title FROM achievements 
WHERE id not in 
(SELECT achievement_id FROM achievements_user WHERE user_id = 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the concrete test (but a *positive* test) up into the join, otherwise your left join silently becomes an inner join:

```
SELECT achievements.id, achievements.title, achievements.sub_title
FROM achievements                          -- all achievements potentially returned
LEFT JOIN achievements_user ON achievements.id = achievements_user.achievement_id 
    AND achievements_user.user_id = 123    -- tries to join to all user's achievements 
WHERE achievements_user.user_id IS NULL    -- only missed joins returned
```

You don't need `DISTINCT`.